# Как в python работать с указателями? Как узнать адрес (значение указателя)?

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

В python есть замечательный модуль ctypes однако не понятно как работать в нём с указателями. Например для int

```
from ctypes import *
int_ptr = pointer(c_int32(12))
```

Как теперь узнать адрес самого c_int32(12)  и как работать с адресной арифметикой?

Comment: какую арифметику вы ожидаете от указателя на скаляр?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Get the memory address pointed to by a ctypes pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9687002/4279)

Answer (score 2):

У обычных указателей нет `value` атрибута (который мог бы адрес содержать — указатель это переменная, которая адрес содержит в Си). У `c_void_p` есть `value` атрибут (любой указатель можно в `void*` превратить), который позволяет получить адрес Си объекта, на который указатель ссылается:

```
address = cast(int_ptr, c_void_p).value
```

Или `address = c_void_p.from_buffer(int_ptr).value` ([может быть быстрее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234970/how-to-get-the-pointer-address-of-a-ctypes-c-char-p-instance#comment52357759_32235051)).

В ctypes также есть [addressof() функция](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.addressof), которая соответствующий адрес буфера в памяти возвращает (для произвольных объектов):

```
address = addressof(int_ptr.contents)
```

это похоже на `&(*int_ptr)` в Си. Адрес во всех случаях одинаковый.

Арифметика получается из `*(p + i) == p[i]`, то есть можно написать `int_ptr[0]` (эквивалентно `*int_ptr`) -- не `0` индексы для указателя на скаляр ожидаемо могут к segfault привести.

Типы указателя и тип массива различны. В ctypes может быть необходимо явно  указатель в массив преобразовать и наоборот. [How to convert pointer to c array to python array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7543675/4279).