# Получение доступа к объекту через идентификатор

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо реализовать что-то типа "указателей" на пайтоне...
Появилась идея использовать `id(obj)`, но появился вопрос: как мне получить обратно доступ к объекту по возвращаемому значению от `id()`?

Или может есть более удобный способ?

Comment: Можете почитать про это [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762551/Как-в-python-работать-с-указателями-Как-узнать-адрес-значение-указателя) или [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/454324/)

Comment: Почему бы не хранить просто ссылку на объект?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Через `ctypes`, если я правильно понял "получить обратно доступ к объекту":

```py
import ctypes

text = "may force be with you"
obj_id = id(text)

print(ctypes.cast(obj_id, ctypes.py_object).value)
```

напечатает:

> may force be with you

Comment: Интересная вещь :) Но сложно представить ее полезность в коде, когда можно просто ссылки хранить

Comment: Спасибо, именно то, что я искал

Comment: @gil9red Если только кто-то не хочет хитрым образом записать объект одного типа, а потом обращаться к его данным как к другому типу :)